# UIDevice uniqueIdentifier in iOS6 / 6.0.1

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier, uidevice

I know this is a well known and discussed issue. And I've already search here for what I want to know and couldn't get any conclusion.

UniqueIdentifier is still working in iOS6.0.1 (although it's deprecated since 5.0, I know). But is it possible that it can be returning some different (or nil) string than in older OS versions? And possibly only in some specific devices? I've managed to test in 5.1 and the returned string is equal to the one in 6.0.1.

I've read a lot saying that it doesn't work anymore, but fact is it still works. Now the question is, does it still work exactly as before? Could something have changed due to deprecation? I know I shouldn't depend on uid anymore, but I'm just trying to analyze and debug some strange behaviors I'm having in an app lately.

Thanks,
Francisco

Comment: Deprecated means, it is still working, but it will stop working sometime in the future, in a next iOS update. So maybe in iOS7 this is not available anymore, meaning your app will get probably a nill value on that iOS version... You should just use the mac Address of the device's Wifi module and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6 and above you should use NSUUID:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I realize that doesn't answer your actual question.  Apple doesn't want you to use the older method anymore for whatever reason and there *have* been cases of applications being rejected for using it.  So whether or not it works is probably a lesser issue if you won't even be able to submit it ;).  I don't think the mechanism has changed though.